# Setting order/position - resetting by two vars

Tags: mysql, sql, position

I want to ask if this can be done by MySQL only and not by php code

i have a table that has

```
ID, CATID, Order
```

i know i can set the order by

```
SET @pos := 0; UPDATE products SET order = @pos :=@pos +1 ORDER BY order;
```

but how can i reset it ( starting from 0 on each catid ).

In php i can select each catid and run diferent sql each time.

Is there a solution of MySQL only?

( Also propose a title. I didnt know how to write it :P )

Comment: Could you provide some context as to why this is necessary?  There's probably a better way to fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new variable @cat. Compare with catid and reset the @pos on catid change

```
SET @pos := 0;
SET @cat:= 0;
UPDATE products p join 
  (
  select id, 
         @pos:=if(@cat<>catid,0,@pos+1) as new_order,
         @cat:=catid
  from products
  ORDER BY order
  ) p2 on p.id=p2.id
SET order = p2.new_order;
```

Comment: Shouldn't be ordered by cat_id also cause when a cat_id changes order will be reset each time ???

Comment: I don't know your table structures so can't say. If you need custom ordering just add the necessary fields to ORDER BY